# Remove white background from progressdialog

Tags: android

Good day, faced with problem, that I can't remove white background behind the `ProgressDialog`. I'm trying to use `background=#00FFFFFF` for `RelativeLayout` but no result. How to remove this background or make it transparent ?

[image]

My code for `ProgressDialog`:

```
public class Loading {
    private Context context;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public Loading(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void show() {
        getDialog().show();
        getDialog().setContentView(R.layout.dialog_spinner);

    }

    public void dismiss() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void error() {
        dismiss();
    }

    public void success() {
        dismiss();
    }

    public void error(RetrofitError error) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(error);
    }

    public ProgressDialog getDialog() {
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        }
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

dialog_spinner layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_progress_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And dialog_progress_background shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="#80000000" />


</shape>
```

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957263/why-the-background-of-progressdialog-doesnt-set-to-the-transparent/21957406#21957406)

Comment: @MD This sample break my rounded corners

Comment: You need to do some customization as per your requirement

Comment: I tried that, but there were 2 problems: 1 I can't remove padding and I can`t implement rounded-colors

Comment: @MD check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220756/style-for-android-progressdialog)

Answer (score 3):

***Add below code***

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);     
getDialog().setContentView(R.layout.dialog_spinner);
```

**I hope it should work for you.**